# Problem with IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have the following code:

```
function header(){
 experience += '';
 var expimage = '';
 for(var cik=0;cik<experience.length;cik++){
  switch(experience[cik]){
   case '0':
   expimage += 'img0';
   break;
   case '1':
   expimage += 'img1';
      break;
      case '2':
      expimage += 'img2';
      break;
      case '3':
      expimage += 'img3';
      break;
      case '4':
      expimage += 'img4';
      break;
      case '5':
      expimage += 'img5';
      break;
      case '6':
      expimage += 'img6';
      break;
      case '7':
      expimage += 'img7';
      break;
      case '8':
      expimage += 'img8';
      break;
      case '9':
      expimage += 'img9';
      break;
  }
 }
 document.getElementById('level').innerHTML = expimage;
 alert(expimage);
}
```

But it only work on chrome or mozilla. It shows up an empty alert box, but it work on firefox and chrome. I tried to alert each variable after each line, and I noticed that the problem shows when I tried to alert(experience[0]) ,it shows undefined, the other steps are working.

Comment: FYI - The entire switch statement can be replaced with `expimage += 'img' + experience[cik];`, assuming there isn't some value in experience that misses the cases.

Comment: I use the switch because the img1, img2... are the URLs of the images, and the images are uploaded to photobucket, so the center of the url is not the same at all images.

Comment: Try throwing an `alert(experience);` at the top of your function to make sure `experience` contains the value you think it does.  We could also use some more information on what behavior you're seeing in IE.

Comment: the fact that it's showing up at all makes it very unlikely that the issue is in this case statement, it's in the display of this image.

Comment: Nothing can be suggested until you tell us what is `experience` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you show the full code and HTML so I can see how you are calling this method and how 'experience' is defined?

Also, It looks like you could replace your switch statement with this:

```
expimage += 'img' + experience[cik];
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I found the problem:
IE can`t split a string to it`s characters because i tried to alert experience[0] and it says undefined....

Comment: @coolboycsaba Edit your question to include this new information, and you may receive a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `experience` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere before it is used.  You probably want to pass it into the function as an argument; you can modify your function to accept the argument like this:

```
function header(experience) {
    // ....
}
```

Without more information on what `experience` is and the code that is calling `header`, it's difficult to answer your question more thoroughly.

Comment: i don`t think this is the problem because if i alert the experience it works, the problem is only when I want to split it into characters